# Where is Android boot animation saved?

Tags: boot-animation

When you start an Android device, there is an animation showed, usually "Android", but sometimes the manufacturer's logo.

Where is this animation stored? I have looked in the `boot.img`, but can't see it there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The boot animation is normally located in `/system/media` under the name `bootanimation.zip`. This is a zip file containing one or more directories named `part0`, `part1`, `part2`, and so on, and a text file named desc.txt. The directories each contain a number of still images, JPEG or PNG, sequentially numbered, for example, `0001.png`, `0002.png`, `0003.png`, and so on. The text file is a simple description of the properties, such as how many times to loop each directory, the pixel size of the images, and the framerate. Like this:

```
width height framerate
p loop pause directory
```

For example:

```
1080 1920 20
p 1 0 part0
p 0 0 part1
```

0 for loop means that it loops until the boot process is complete, and the pause is specified in number of frames, so with a framerate of 20, a pause of 1 would mean 0.05 seconds pause before moving on to the next loop or the next part.

Some manufacturers may use a proprietary file format, which may or may not have a different name than `bootanimation.zip`, so make sure that your current file uses the above format before replacing it with a custom one. If the boot animation is corrupted, the phone may boot loop or simply ignore the animation.

The file should be owned by `root:root` and have permissions set to `644 (rw-r--r--)`. It must **not** be compressed.

Answer (score 1):

The boot animation is located at

```
/(Home directory) > System > Media > ... (for me it's bootanimation.zip)
```

And of course you need a file explorer and a rooted phone I guess.

Comment: You don't need a rooted device to reach it

Answer (score 1):

- A root is required to perform this task.
- Use any file explorer application such as `ES File Explorer`, with root access.
- Go to the root directory of `internal / system / media`. You can see a file named `bootanimation.zip`, which is the one that loaded during boot.

Extracting the zip may display multiple folders named as `part0`, `part1`, `part2`,.. and `desc.txt`.

Comment: You don't need a rooted device to reach it

Answer (score 1):

If you have a computer with Android Debug Bridge (ADB) available, you can run this command to find its location:

`$ adb shell`

`# find . -iname "bootanimation.zip" 2>/dev/null`

On one of my devices it was stored in `/oem/media/bootanimation.zip` and on the other device it was stored in `/product/media/bootanimation.zip`

Answer (score 0):

For me, on Pixel 6 with Android 13, it's actually on:

```
/system/product/media/bootanimation-dark.zip  

/system/product/media/bootanimation.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you can override the boot animation on a device. Create a boot animation file, as described in the other answers, and copy it to `/data/local`, which is writable by adb without rooting:

```
adb push bootanimation.zip /data/local
```

Source: [Emteria article on boot animations](https://emteria.com/blog/custom-boot-animation-android). I have not tried this yet.